# Does Joomla! 3 have a limit on installed templates?

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a project where I need to provide something like 250 templates. So the final user can change the template in Backend.

My question is about the number of templates. 250 is a big number (perhaps meaningless), but is the objective.

Anyone know if Joomla! has any limitation about this? And the only way is install one by one?

Comment: You mean you want to ship Joomla! to your clients with 250 pre-installed templates?

Comment: @ValentinDespa, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of installing them 1 by 1, you could extract each one into the "templates" folder, then in the Joomla Backend, go to:

```
Extensions >> Extension Manager >> Discover
```

Then clock the "Discover" button in the top right, whch will then display all your extracted templates that haven't been installed properly. Select them all and click "Install".

This will make life a little easier and be quicker I would have thought.

As Valentin Despa also said, Joomla 3.0 is the short term release, therefore if you want a site as big as something that requires 250 templates, I would recommend using Joomla 2.5, as it's the long term release and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know of any imposed limitations, so you need to test it. Maybe also renaming the same template and installing it multiple times will do the trick.

I would like to emphasize that Joomla! 3.0 is a short time release. This means maintaining 250 templates through 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and 3.5 releases will be no easy task.

Pun in balance advantages / disadvantages.

Looking forward to other opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your task more easy adding different styles for the same template. 
You can build different CSS files for each version of your template and let your customers choose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent limitation. The question is what is whether it is sensible. It's potentially a ton of files but you might be able to set up a share space for your javascript.   Most like, as has been said by others, you would be better off using template styles since it is pretty hard to imagine a uses case for 250 different index.php files but it's certainly easy to imagine one for 250 different sets of css if you are running something where there are a lot of very distinct subsites.  Especially with bootstrap that is very easy to do.